# Does 'make'-ing something from source make it self-contained?

Tags: makefile, build, cmake

Forgive me before I start, as I'm not a C / C++ etc programmer, a mere PHP one :) but I've been working on projects that use some others sourced from online open source repos, such as svn and git. For some of these projects, I need to install libraries and then run "./configure", "make" and then "make all" (as an example) and I do this on a "build" virtual machine to get the binaries that I need to use within my project.

The ultimate goal of some of *my* projects is to then take these "compiled" (if that's the correct term) binaries and place them onto a virtual machine which I would then re-distribute (according to licenses etc).

My question is this : when I build these binaries on my build machine, with all the pre-requisities that I need in order to build them in the first place ("build-essential" and "cmake" and "gcc" etc etc) - once the binaries are on my build machine (in /usr/lib for example) are they self-contained to the point that I can merely copy those /usr/lib binary files that the build created and place them in the same folder on the virtual machines that I would distribute, *without* the build servers having all the build components installed on them?

With all the dependencies that I would need to build the source in the place, would that finally built binary contain them all in itself, or would I have to include them on the distributed servers as well?

Would that work? Is the question a little too general and perhaps it would all depend on what I'm building?

**Update from original posting after a couple of responses**

I will be distributing the VMs myself, inasmuch as I will build them and then install my projects upon them. Therefore, I know the OS and environment completely. I just don't want to "bloat" them with unnecessary software that's been installed that I don't actually need because the compiled executables I will place on the distributed VMs in *for example* /usr/local/bin ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on how you **link** your program to libraries it depends on. In most cases, the default is to link **dynamically**, which means that you need to distribute your executable **along** its deps. You can check out what libraries are required to run the file using `ldd` command.

Theoretically, you can link everything **statically**, which means that library code would be compiled into executable. Thus, executable would really be self-contained, but linking statically is not always possible. This depends on actual libraries you are using and probably require playing with `./configure` args when building them.

Finally, there are some liraries that always linked dynamically, such as `libc`. The good thing is that machine you are distributing to would surely have this library. The bad thing is that versions of these libraries may differ, and you might face ABI mismatch.

In short, if your project not huge and there is possibility to link everything statically, go this way. If not, read about [AppImage](http://appimage.org/) and [Docker](https://www.docker.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The distribution of built libraries and headers (binary distribution) is a possible way and should work. (I do it in my projects always.)

It is not necessary that all of the libraries you built are installed into /usr/lib. To keep your target machine clean you can install it in other folder to, e.g.

- `/usr/local/MYLIB/lib/libmylib.so`
- `/usr/local/MYLIB/include/mylib.h`
- `/usr/local/MYOTHERLIB/lib/libmyotherlib.so`
- `/usr/local/MYOTHERLIB/include/libmyotherlib.so`

Advantages:

1. Easy installation, easy remove
2. All files within one subfolder, no files are missing, no mix with other libs

Disadvantage:

1. The loader must know the extra search path